# Same primary key for multiple tables vs separate primary keys

Tags: postgresql, database-design, primary-key

Lets assume we have an employee table as below

**employee**

id (PK) | name | date_of_birth | age | created_at

We have a scenario where we need to add some metadata for each employee and not every employee will have this metadata, so we create a new table as below

**employee_metadata**

id (PK) | employee_id (PK) | ... | created_at

There is a 1-1 mapping between both the tables

What would be a better design practice for the primary key of `employee_metadata` table, 1 or 2?

1. A separate auto-incrementing id
2. Using `employee_id` of `employee` table

Answer (score 0):

Entia non sunt multiplicanda praeter necessitatem! ([Occam's razor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor)).

If all you're doing is splitting the employee table (**once** and **only once** for some/all employees), then use the original `PRIMARY KEY`! Saves on space both on your hard disk and in your brain! The new `PK` is just extra baggage in this case!

However, one potential caveats have been pointed out by other posters:

- multiple metadata records to be associated with a single employee

However, if you don't need it **now**, you're better off to apply the [`YAGNI`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) ("You aren't gonna need it") principle.

Comment: Using the PK from employee table makes sense for all CRUD based scenarios. Also thinking if an auto incrementing ID would make sense for any postgres optimisations?

Comment: Well, compound natural `PK`s are (potentially much) bigger than a surrogate `IDENTITY` generated `PK`s - that's an optimisation in itself - less data dupliction (in the heap **and** the index). This is especially true if one uses `SMALLINT` (two bytes) or `MEDIUMINT` (four bytes) keys - I find there's almost an automatic unthinking reflex to use an `INT` (8 bytes on 64 bit systems) without analysing if the data really requires 9.2*10^18 keys. The only reason not to use one is the [German tank problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem) - never publically expose your `PK`s.

Comment: I feel I disagree @Vérace. In the metadata table we might find 10-20-30 entries for each employee. We need a new PK.

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani - I did say `If all you're doing is splitting the employee table` - it seems fairly clear from the question that it will happen once and once only for **some** employees - but I've added a clarification to my answer just in case!